# Component updated in react-test-renderer when Redirect is rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-router-v4, react-test-renderer

I'm currently writing test for my login form written in react-redux using react-router-dom.

My component looks like this:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      isAuthenticated,
      ...
    } = this.props

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }

    return (
      <div style={{ ...styles.main }}>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

To test this component I have written the following test:

```
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom"

import LoginPage from "./LoginPage"

it("renders a redirect if the user is authenticated", () => {

  const tree = renderer
    .create(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <LoginPage
          isAuthenticated={ true } />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    .toJSON()

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

This test mounts the component correctly and "renders" the Redirect, but it also seems to triggers an update. This rerenders the redirect and gives me the following warning in my test output:

```
console.error node_modules\warning\warning.js:51
  Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"
```

How can I prevent this warning from showing up?

Thanks!